# How to trigger only my requests using Xdebug on remote server

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug code that is on remote server.

I'm using

- Ubuntu 16 server, LEMP, PHP 7.0 as remote server
- OSX, PhpStorm, Chrome Xdebug helper as local environment

So, when

- Xdebug connection is established by

  ```
  ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 {username}@{serverhost}
  ```
- Xdebug helper in debug mode
- PhpStorm start listening is enabled

Xdebug triggers to each requests not only from my browser or PhpStorm, but from all other users from the internet.

Is it normal?

Is it possible to watch only requests initiated from my PhpStorm or from my Chrome requests? If yes, so how to setup?

Comment: Make sure that you have `xdebug.remote_autostart = 0`.

Comment: Yes, it was 1, but when I've switched it to 0, xdebug stops working at all

Comment: So .. use other means of triggering Xdebug -- cookie, GET/POST parameter, `xdebug_break();` in your code etc.

Comment: xdebug_break();

Comment: what do you mean? what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I do not know. I see little to no info from you about your setup. In any case: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: Your answer was right. After I changed autostart to 0, I didn't catch any requests. The reason was that I didn't follow documentation at all.. I've tried to debug iframe, so need to start debugging on iframe, not the parent website. Also an order is important: put breakpoints, start listening, establish ssh tunnel, start debugging. Thanks for help.

Comment: @LazyOne Your answer helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Xdebug triggers to each requests not only from my browser or PhpStorm, but from all other users from the internet.
>
> Is it normal?

That depends on your Xdebug configuration. Right now it looks like it's configured to automatically attempt to debug every single request (not a good idea in many situations).

> Is it possible to watch only requests initiated from my PhpStorm or from my Chrome requests? If yes, so how to setup?

Yes, make sure that `xdebug.remote_autostart` is turned off (set to `0`/`no`).

Then just follow the official guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Xdebug will see your Xdebug cookie set by Chrome Xdebug Helper (or GET/POST parameter if you pass it manually in URL/request) and will try to debug only those requests.

P.S. There is another scenarios where the aforementioned option will not help.. but so far it does not look like you are having that case (would need to see *much more* details for that).